# Override add in HashSet

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I'm just trying to write my own implementation of HashSet add(). The code is not using my implementation but going in the default one.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateElements<E> extends HashSet<E>{

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        System.out.println("Using this");
        return super.add(e);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String names[] = { "Java", "JavaScript", "Ruby", "C", "Python", "Java", "Python"};

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        boolean isAdded = set.add(names[i]);
        if (!isAdded) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate Found: "+names[i]);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I am trying to modify the add method to ignore case while adding elements.

Comment: You should be declaring set as an instance of DuplicateElements rather than HashSet... Precisely this line. HashSet<String> set= new DuplicateElements<String>();

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

Well it seems like you are using default `HashSet`, maybe you meant

```
 HashSet<String> set = new DuplicateElements<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is this line of code:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

The above code still uses the default implementation of the HashSet.
You should use your own implementation of HashSet by doing this:

```
DuplicateElements<String> set = new DuplicateElements<String>();
```